# Add Class to outside div with specific class

Tags: jquery

Hey I try to add a class to the `div` with "teaser-background item-1" class when I hover the `div` with "teaser-item item-1" class or when I hover "item-2" then add a class to the `div` with "teaser-item item-2".

#HTML

```
<div class="teaser-home-container">
   <div class="teaser-home owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="owl-item">
         <div class="teaser-item item-1"></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item">
         <div class="teaser-item item-2"></div> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="teaser-home--background">
      <div class="teaser-background item-1"></div>
      <div class="teaser-background item-2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

#Jquery

```
$thisClass = $(this).find("div[class^=item-]").attr('class');
$('.owl-item').hover(function(){
   $(this).parents('.teaser-home-container').find($thisClass).addClass('hover');
};
```

Comment: `attr('class')` is going to return something like `teaser-item item-1`.  And `find(teaser-item item-1)` is an invalid selector later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.teaser-item.item-1').hover(function() {
    $('.teaser-background.item-1').addClass('hover');
});
$('.teaser-item.item-2').hover(function() {
    $('.teaser-background.item-2').addClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the job for you, just by identifying the divs by ID

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".teaser-item").hover(function(){
                var id = this.id;
                $("#hover"+id).addClass("hover");

            });
        });
    </script>

        <div class="teaser-home-container">
           <div class="teaser-home owl-carousel owl-theme">
              <div class="owl-item">
                 <div class="teaser-item" id="item-1">Item1</div> 
              </div>
              <div class="owl-item">
                 <div class="teaser-item" id="item-2">Item2</div> 
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="teaser-home--background">
              <div class="teaser-background" id="hoveritem-1">Hitem1</div>
              <div class="teaser-background" id="hoveritem-2">Hitem2</div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Not a good idea to work with classes in your case .. It can be done by using `data` attribute

<sup>You can Start from here</sup>

```js
$('.owl-item .teaser-item').hover(function(){
  var GetData = $(this).data("item");
   $(this).closest('.teaser-home-container').find('[data-bg="'+GetData+'"]').addClass('hover');
},
function(){
  $(this).closest('.teaser-home-container').find('[data-bg]').removeClass("hover");
});
```

```css
.hover{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="teaser-home-container">
   <div class="teaser-home owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="owl-item">
         <div class="teaser-item" data-item="1">Item 1</div> 
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item">
         <div class="teaser-item" data-item="2">Item 2</div> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="teaser-home--background">
      <div class="teaser-background" data-bg="1">Bg 1</div>
      <div class="teaser-background" data-bg="2">Bg 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```